# Hiding files that have been git rm --cached from the list of changed files in GitHub for Windows

Tags: github-for-windows

In GitHub for Windows, files that have been `git rm --cached` still appear in the list of changed files. Is there any way to hide them?

[image]

Comment: What are you wishing to do ? --cached just remove the file from the index without removing from disk, but the change has to be commit, you may rewrite/rebase your repo to remove those file from the version control but that's a hard path.

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks, it looks like I had wrongly assumed I didn't have to add the files to my `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to add the files to your `.gitignore` file.

http://www.gitguys.com/how-to-remove-a-file-from-git-source-control-but-not-delete-it/:

> The git rm command will allows you to remote a file from git control.
>   The –cached option to git remove allows you to leave it on your hard
>   drive.
>
> Every once in awhile a file gets checked into git that isn’t supposed
>   to be there. Common examples are configuration files, project files
>   generated by your IDE with personal settings and even the occasional
>   object file that someone decided to check in. These files are needed,
>   so often you can’t delete them entirely and the process of copying
>   them somewhere else, removing them from git and then replacing is
>   painful, not to mention prone to error.
>
> By adding the –cached option to the git rm command, you are able to
>   remote the file file from git control while keeping the file in your
>   working tree. They command syntax is:
>
> ```
> git rm --cached file
> ```
>
> Git will no longer track this file even though it is still on your
>   hard drive.
>
> After running the above command, be sure to add an entry to your `.gitignore` file so that ‘file’ doesn’t show up in ‘git status’ and that it can’t accidentally be re-added later.